# Sorting with two digits in string - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and I have a hard time solving this. 
I am trying to sort a list to be able to human sort it 1) by the first number and 2) the second number. I would like to have something like this:

```
'1-1bird'
'1-1mouse'
'1-1nmouses'
'1-2mouse'
'1-2nmouses'
'1-3bird'
'10-1birds'
(...)
```

Those numbers can be from 1 to 99 ex: 99-99bird is possible.
This is the code I have after a couple of headaches. Being able to then sort by the following first letter would be a bonus.
Here is what I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


myList = list()
myList = ['1-10bird', '1-10mouse', '1-10nmouses', '1-10person', '1-10cat', '1-11bird', '1-11mouse', '1-11nmouses', '1-11person', '1-11cat', '1-12bird', '1-12mouse', '1-12nmouses', '1-12person', '1-13mouse', '1-13nmouses', '1-13person', '1-14bird', '1-14mouse', '1-14nmouses', '1-14person', '1-14cat', '1-15cat', '1-1bird', '1-1mouse', '1-1nmouses', '1-1person', '1-1cat', '1-2bird', '1-2mouse', '1-2nmouses', '1-2person', '1-2cat', '1-3bird', '1-3mouse', '1-3nmouses', '1-3person', '1-3cat', '2-14cat', '2-15cat', '2-16cat', '2-1bird', '2-1mouse', '2-1nmouses', '2-1person', '2-1cat', '2-2bird', '2-2mouse', '2-2nmouses', '2-2person']


def mysort(x,y):
x1=""
y1=""

for myletter in x :
    if myletter.isdigit() or "-" in myletter: 
        x1=x1+myletter

x1 = x1.split("-")

for myletter in y :
    if myletter.isdigit() or "-" in myletter: 
        y1=y1+myletter

y1 = y1.split("-")


if x1[0]>y1[0]:
    return 1
elif x1[0]==y1[0]:
    if x1[1]>y1[1]:
        return 1
    elif x1==y1:
        return 0
    else :
        return -1
else :
    return -1




myList.sort(mysort)
print myList
```

Thanks !

Martin

Comment: Do you pass if someone does this assignment for you on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some good ideas with splitting on `'-'` and using `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`, but then we'll use those to create a function that takes in an item and returns a "clean" version of the item, which can be easily sorted. It will create a three-digit, zero-padded representation of the first number, then a similar thing with the second number, then the "word" portion (instead of just the first character). The result looks something like `"001001bird"` (that won't display - it'll just be used internally). The built-in function `sorted()` will use this callback function as a key, taking each element, passing it to the callback, and basing the sort order on the returned value. In the test, I use the `*` operator and the `sep` argument to print it without needing to construct a loop, but looping is perfectly fine as well.

```
def callback(item):
    phrase = item.split('-')
    first = phrase[0].rjust(3, '0')
    second = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, phrase[1])).rjust(3, '0')
    word = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, phrase[1]))
    return first + second + word
```

Test:

```
>>> myList = ['1-10bird', '1-10mouse', '1-10nmouses', '1-10person', '1-10cat', '1-11bird', '1-11mouse', '1-11nmouses', '1-11person', '1-11cat', '1-12bird', '1-12mouse', '1-12nmouses', '1-12person', '1-13mouse', '1-13nmouses', '1-13person', '1-14bird', '1-14mouse', '1-14nmouses', '1-14person', '1-14cat', '1-15cat', '1-1bird', '1-1mouse', '1-1nmouses', '1-1person', '1-1cat', '1-2bird', '1-2mouse', '1-2nmouses', '1-2person', '1-2cat', '1-3bird', '1-3mouse', '1-3nmouses', '1-3person', '1-3cat', '2-14cat', '2-15cat', '2-16cat', '2-1bird', '2-1mouse', '2-1nmouses', '2-1person', '2-1cat', '2-2bird', '2-2mouse', '2-2nmouses', '2-2person']
>>> print(*sorted(myList, key=callback), sep='\n')
1-1bird
1-1cat
1-1mouse
1-1nmouses
1-1person
1-2bird
1-2cat
1-2mouse
1-2nmouses
1-2person
1-3bird
1-3cat
1-3mouse
1-3nmouses
1-3person
1-10bird
1-10cat
1-10mouse
1-10nmouses
1-10person
1-11bird
1-11cat
1-11mouse
1-11nmouses
1-11person
1-12bird
1-12mouse
1-12nmouses
1-12person
1-13mouse
1-13nmouses
1-13person
1-14bird
1-14cat
1-14mouse
1-14nmouses
1-14person
1-15cat
2-1bird
2-1cat
2-1mouse
2-1nmouses
2-1person
2-2bird
2-2mouse
2-2nmouses
2-2person
2-14cat
2-15cat
2-16cat
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are very respectable, I'm sure, but for full credit you should ensure that your answer fits on a single line and uses as many list comprehensions as possible:

```
import itertools
[''.join(r) for r in sorted([[''.join(x) for _, x in
           itertools.groupby(v, key=str.isdigit)]
           for v in myList], key=lambda v: (int(v[0]), int(v[2]), v[3]))]
```

That should do nicely:

```
['1-1bird',
 '1-1cat',
 '1-1mouse',
 '1-1nmouses',
 '1-1person',
 '1-2bird',
 '1-2cat',
 '1-2mouse',
 ...
 '2-2person',
 '2-14cat',
 '2-15cat',
 '2-16cat']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need leading zeros. Strings are sorted alphabetically with the order different from the one for digits. It should be

```
'01-1bird'
'01-1mouse'
'01-1nmouses'
'01-2mouse'
'01-2nmouses'
'01-3bird'
'10-1birds'
```

As you you see 1 goes after 0.